# iOS: How to accomplish circular "zoom in/out" animation

Tags: ios, animation, geometry, interaction

How can I accomplish this effect using iOS:

[image: arrows demo app]

If the GIF above isn't self-explanatory, the requirements are:

1. The bars in the waveform must be configurable in terms of length and color
2. When the waveform is touched and scrolled outside the "clip" range, the waveform "zooms out" meaning that the width of the bars and distance between them decreases and the number of bars increases
3. When the waveform is released, the waveform "zooms in" meaning that the width of the bars and distance between them increases and the number of bars decreases

**Solution A:**

I tried using *CAReplicatorLayer* (following an [activity indicator tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20210129191414/http://www.ios-animations-by-emails.com/posts/2015-march)) and I was able to satisfy requirements #1 and #2. I am not able to control the individual bar length and colors.

**Solution B:**

I tried using *CGPathCreateCopyByDashingPath* (following this [thread](http://CGPathCreateCopyByDashingPath)) but I had even less control of bar properties (I couldn't control length, color, or width).

**Other ideas:**

- Create circle bezier path
- Add bars to the path
- Add keypath animation to move bars around the path (like in [this tutorial](https://mathewsanders.com/animations-in-swift-part-two/))
- Adjust the width of all the bars
- Use UIKit Dynamics (e.g. gravity) to attract bars to bottom of circle path on "zoom out" and remove gravity to "zoom in"